# julia virtualenv asks for os package which does not exists

Tags: virtualenv, julia

**Tried to work with Julia in a virtual environment using below command:**

```
virtualenv  -p julia-1.0.2/bin/julia julia
```

**I got this error:**

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter julia-1.0.2/bin/julia
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package os not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("os")` to install the os package.

Stacktrace:
 [1] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:823
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [5] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:231
 [6] _start() at ./client.jl:425
in expression starting at /home/ebasfad/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/virtualenv.py:5
```

**I tires to install the "os" package but it seems no such packages**

Answer (score 3):

`virtualenv` is used to create isolated Python environments and not Julia environments. The command you give tries to find Python package `os` using Julia executable thinking that it is a Python interpreter. That is the reason for the error.

With Julia 1.0 and its package manager [`Pkg`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/index.html) (Pkg3), you can create your own *projects* (similar to `virtualenv` environments) within Julia and manage your packages for your projects, as you please.

Note that `Pkg` comes built-in. See here to learn how to create a project with `Pkg`: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/index.html#Creating-your-own-projects-1

This is the documentation for `Pkg`: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/index.html